# manage feature/bugfix branch artifacts

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, nexus

We are using Maven to build deploy our artifacts and our repository manager is nexus. All our applications are java applications. We are using Git as source code management tool and Jenkins to build the applications. Now coming to the situation where we are in, 
As usual develop and release branch builds are going to repository manager to separate repositories [Eg: RELEASE & SNAPSHOT] and the dependent applications consumes the artifacts based on the pom dependencies. 
For feature & bugfix branches, we are creating dynamic adhoc temp repositories groups in repository manager with parent as RELEASE. These branches are getting created at the time of build starts for feature/bugfix branches [by the internal jenkins lib we wrote, this will take the name of the branch from ticket associated with feature / bugfix branches in git].
Currently the problem statement is, we have multiple feature/bugfix branches in all apps. Due to this lot of repositories gets created in  Nexus and taking some time to sync the artifacts. Once we remove all old repos, it behaves normal. 
I require help in, how to manage feature/bugfix branch artifacts in repository manager. Personally i feel temp repo is not good process. 

Whether branch qualifier helps in it? or anyother feasible solutions. ?

Comment: This may sound like an upsell, but do you know about/have considered the Professional (licensed) Staging solution?  Sounds like you're working around it.

Comment: We have licensed version only. Just checking is there any option to manage the feature branches

Comment: If you have the licensed version, what about Staging doesn't work for you?  You could also contact support, as that's something you pay for.

Comment: Let me go around with staging and update